# Trouble with JAR creation

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

sorry if this is a simple question but I'm having trouble exporting my java project into a JAR file.  I'm getting the following error:

```
JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.
  com/appiancorp/plugins/capitalize/theFunction [in Capitalize] is not on its project's build path
  Unable to get package fragment root: Capitalize/com/appiancorp/plugins/capitalize/theFunction/Capitalize.java
    com/appiancorp/plugins/capitalize/theFunction [in Capitalize] is not on its project's build path
```

I guess I need to add the "theFunction" class to my buildpath? But I don't understand how to do that...Thanks for the help

EDIT:
I'm using files from the StringTokenizer class in my project and thus importing stuff from java.util.StringTokenizer.  Could the problem be I'm not adding that class to the JAR files?

Darby

Comment: What Java IDE are you using?  Eclipse?

Comment: This really shouldn't be a classpath problem. Fundamentally, 'jar' is an application. You can run it on the command line, and in fact I suspect that's what "theFunction" does. So what you have is a broken 3rd party app. My recommendation to fix is to import your project into Eclipse and use Eclipse's Export functionality to export to a Jar

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and am trying to export the project as a JAR File.

Comment: @Darby I do this all the time so I know this works. If it's not working for you, you might want to think about re-installing Eclipse

Comment: @ctrlaltdlt  Hmm that could be the problem, but I bet its just something stupid I've done.  I wrote this small function so its not really a 3rd party application I think...Maybe I just didn't include a JAR file that I needed like a java.util file or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing class belongs to a jar from the company(3d party)
http://www.appian.com/
you need to find that missing jar and add it to class path

Comment: I tried changing some stuff around and I don't understand why it would be a JAR from appian.  I created a java project with a folder hierarchy like Capitalize/com/appiancorp/pluins/capitalize/theFunction/Capitalize.java

In the Capitalize class, I have a line like:
 
package com.appiancorp.plugins.capitalize.theFunction; and a method within a Capitalize class that just returns an empty string and I still receive the same error

Comment: try another path /com/appiancorp/plugins/capitalize

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I put it in the Capitalize/src path and it exported into a JAR file.  Any idea why one path would work and one wouldn't?

Comment: just a good guess. a standard java package path should start with the top domain com,org, etc, then company name then whatever else.but I|m still not sure whether your jar will work everywhere without the missing jar. you might get a runtime excpetion though